# ASP MVC Redirect to Request.UrlReferrer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm trying to implement multilanguage on my web application.

Everything was working fine but after some testing i've stumbled upon some weird interaction.

Let me first explain what i tried to do...
When language is changed, I tried to return the user to the page he visited when he tried to change the language on the web application. This is the code that I used to accomplish that.

```
var returnPage = Request.UrlReferrer;
        if (returnPage != null)
        {
            return Redirect(returnPage.ToString());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

As I said before everything seemed to work, but on a single controller/action, this redirect is acknowledged as Async request. Which then breaks the code. I could fix the problem with some "spaghetti" but I want to do this cleaner.

Now why is Redirect sometimes acknowledged as Async request? Is there any other way of returning user to the last visited page without using Redirect and UrlReferrer so I can avoid that interaction?

Comment: How do you know **acknowledged as Async request.** ?

Comment: In debug mode it goes through if statement : if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) ....

Comment: What was the previous call that happened then?

Comment: I have bunch of Controllers with Index Actions. And I've placed the language changer on top navbar which is fixed and same on all controllers (bootstrap classic theme). I've tested this language change on every other Controller/Index and it reloads page so the navbar labels change (to correct language). Only on 1 controller it goes off like Ajax call and tries to reload content on that page as an ajax call (which is also implemented for some content). When I first visit that controller it acts like a normal call, but once language is changed it goes to ajax for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like the following...

Controller:

```
  // after language is changed    
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
      return Json(new {
        Success: true,
        ReturnPage = returnPage ?? new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home");
      });
    }
    else {
      if (returnPage != null)
      {
        return Redirect(returnPage.ToString());
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

View:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Settings/ChangeLanguage',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {lan: 'en'},
    success: function(result) {
        if (result.Success) {
            window.location = result.ReturnPage;
        }
    }
});
```

That way the code in the controller would work for AJAX and non-AJAX requests. But if you are only calling it with AJAX, you might want to use only the code that returns json.